# What is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^4}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\int_{k}^{k+1} x\ln[(x-k)(k+1-x)]dx$?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, summation

The value of $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^4}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\int_{k}^{k+1} x\ln[(x-k)(k+1-x)]dx$$
is negative inverse of ..

First I solved the integral by shifting the limits and making then 0 and 1 repectively. Then I solved for the rest and ended up getting final answer as 2. But my textbook says it is 0.5. Tried a lot of times to ensure no calculation mistake, but still ended up with 2.
Please help

Comment: $2$ is the reciprocal of $1/2$ It looks like you might have just dropped a minus sign somewhere. But that is an odd/confusing way to ask a question from a textbook.

Comment: Without seeing your calculation, who can say where the error is?

Comment: As to me, the limit is $-{1\over2}$, which is negative inverse of 2, and if the book says otherwise, then the authors got caught in their own net.

Comment: Unless they are using "negative inverse" to mean "additive inverse"?

Comment: @ Ivan Neretin and  user10354138 , I too thought the same but still due to maybe curiosity or no satisfaction asked the question. :-)